# can google oauth 2.0 client secret be hard-coded in client say .apk(android) or .xap(wp7)?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the google oauth2.0 api in an android and wp7 phone app. My question is whether the "client secret" given by google while registering the app be hard-coded in the code(source code will be obfuscated)? (or) should I create a webpage that will have the client secret and authorize accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the key in the XAP, but you should be aware that anyone who really wants it, will get it. Even if it is stored on a server and obtained later through a request, it can still be intercepted. That being said, most of the applications in the Marketplace keep their app keys hard-coded.

Comment: In Google docs, they say "Your webserver should swap that authorization code for a refresh token and access token pair by POSTing it along with your client_id, client_secret and grant_type=authorization_code to our OAuth 2.0 token endpoint." 

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#IA